# which is the best python mongodb lib 

Tags: python, mongodb

I am a mongodb beginner and I use pymongo. I want to know it is the best to control mongodb using python.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pymongo is the best tool for Mongodb in python. And it's the widely used tool. It's getting popular drastically and it has seen so many versions current being PyMongo 1.10.1.   I think you are in the right direction using pymongo

Answer (score 3):

PyMongo is best if you don't need much of schema, ORMs, otherwise as Bastian suggests [MongoKit](http://namlook.github.com/mongokit/) is good and you could/should also have a look at

- [Ming](http://merciless.sourceforge.net/orm.html) which has  sqlalchemy style ORM.
- [MongoEngine](http://mongoengine.org/)

Answer (score 0):

I use MongoKit. It adds some stuff like Models to pymongo but you can still use all pymongo functions.

Link: http://namlook.github.com/mongokit/